# Proof in coq - Predicate logic

Tags: coq, predicate, proof, predicates

Trying to prove the following in coq: 
Prove that the universal quantifier distributes over conjunction
∀x ∈ A, P x ∧ Qx ⇐⇒ (∀x ∈ A, P x) ∧ (∀x ∈ A, Qx)

My Proof so far-

```
Parameter (A : Type).
Parameter (P Q : A -> Prop).

Lemma II3: (forall x : A, P x /\ Q x) <->
           (forall x : A, P x) /\ (forall x : A, Q x).
split.
intro H.
split.
apply H.
intros H1.
Proof.
```

I have tried to split, destruct, and introduce a new hypothesis, but I just can't seem to make it past this point. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a small tip: it would be simpler if you added a proof script written in a regular `.v` file, as opposed to the transcript of an interaction with the proof assistant. That way, it is easier for us to copy your attempt in Coq to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You can edit her question tho.

Comment: Two strange things in your script: the use of `Proof.` in the middle of the proof instead of at the beginning of it; the fact that you handle similar goals (with conclusions `forall x, P x` and `forall x, Q x`) very differently.

Answer (score 2):

this is a pretty easy proof, for example `now intuition; apply H` will solve your goal.

In your case, you should first figure out how the proof works using *pen and paper*, and once you've done that, the proof in Coq will be trivial.